# Seaborn pairplot off-diagonal KDE with two classes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to look at a Seaborn pairplot for two different classes of variables and I'd like to see KDEs on the offdiagonals instead of scatterplots. The documentation has [instructions on how to do a KDE for *all* of the data](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html), but I want to see separate KDEs for each subclass of data. Suggestions welcome!

My code looks something like this:

```
plot = sns.pairplot(
    df,
    vars=labels,
    hue='has_accident',
    palette='Set1',
    diag_kind='kde',
)
```

which results in:

[image]

As you can see the data are sufficiently dense that it is difficult to see the difference in the red and blue data on the off diagonal.

Comment: FWIW the KDE, which is based on a gaussian model, appears poorly suited for your data.

Comment: fair point @mwaskom. i'm going to be messing around with a lot of different feature permutations, others of which i anticipate to be more spherical. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You possibly mean something like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")

g = sns.PairGrid(iris, hue="species", hue_kws={"cmap": ["Blues", "Greens", "Reds"]})
g = g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, lw=3)
g = g.map_offdiag(sns.kdeplot, lw=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]