# Kernel Density Estimation does not Plot in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Following the sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035284/seaborn-pairplot-off-diagonal-kde-with-two-classes):

I was able to recreate what I want to accomplish, a PairGrid with KDE plotted in the off-diagonal from the above example.

However, with my own data, the KDE contour plots are not generated.

Apart from hosting the raw data somewhere for someone to test, is there something I should look out for?  There are no `NaN` or `np.inf` anywhere in the data.  If there are common things to lookout for, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If your KDE contour plots do not display, it could be that you have zero-values in your series.  This turns out to have been my problem, though no error or warning was thrown.  Simply replacing `0` values with `np.nan` then dropping all `np.nan` solved my issue.